# Why does clearing data from a pivot source so slow, especially if I changed the source location to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, caching, pivot-table

I have a 'clear' function that resets a workbook and a pivot table and chart. It must also remove the raw data from a data tab. When I remove/clear/delete the data, the VBA struggles on this line of code. I get Excel may cache things but I've taken a step that should absolutely prevent this. I actually point the Pivot table source to a new range, then refresh cache, then delete the data from where the Pivot no longer points. It's still very slow to delete the data. I've run out of ideas.

The last row of code below is slow(5-10 secs), but only after I refresh the pivot table to the range on the data tab. If the pivot is not refreshed to the data tab (with many rows added), it deletes quickly. How do I get it to do a delete or clear quickly? At that line of execution, there is no other data in the workbook pointed or dependent on the data tab. I do have a pivot chart and a pivot table. I've tried with/without events/calculations/screen updating. Keep in mind some of these lines are only there because I've tried everything I know of. Removing any of the 1 to n lines prior to .delete or .clear does nothing to change the problem.

```
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Data").ManualUpdate = True
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Data").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Global!$E$24:$N25", Version:=6)

Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Data").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Data").RefreshTable
Sheets("Data").rows("3:100000").Delete
```

I expect last line of code to execute in a fraction of a second, not 5 or 10

Comment: Does the "Data" sheet contain a `ListObject`/table, or it's just a plain range? Try `Sheets("Data").Range("3:100000").EntireRow.Delete`, and try actually working out where the data ends instead of hard-coding a large number that presumably is large enough to encompass everything you'll ever need.

Comment: It's raw data, not even a named range. I forgot to mention something that helps. It's clearly connected to the pivot cache refresh. If I add data to the data tab, but never refresh the pivot to the updated data tab, I can delete data on the data tab quickly. However, if the PIvot is refreshed to the updated data tab, this is when the long latency will occur. Again, it makes no sense because I change the data source pointer of the pivot table away from the Data tab before clearing data. I can set the delete range dynamically, but it's still slow.

Comment: More testing and assessment leads me to this: I'm creating a new cache, not deleting the existing one. I believe there is a pre-existing cache still pointed at data I'm deleting. I'd still like a way to remove the data quickly. I found it's much faster to just not add the new cache at all. However, still not ideal as there is some delay. I know there's no way to delete the cache without deleting the pivot table.. but there may be a way to clear the cache or repoint it that I'm unaware of.